# What kind of deciduous tree is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

This image was captured on October 10th, 2020 in Haliburton, Ontario, Canada. Any help identifying the tree species is greatly appreciated. Rob.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a [poplar tree](https://www.canstockphoto.com/autumn-color-of-poplar-leaves-background-41724084.html), very fast growing, light wood, often used for matches, very often has a white saprophytic tea color mushroom growing on the tree stumps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclocybe_aegerita

The description is missing bark photos and leaf anatomy photos. It can also be a birch or a willow, very difficult to ID from just that photo.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't quaking aspen (*Populus tremuloides*), which is in the Poplar family, but called aspens in North America.

Comment: He can tell by comparing the bark which is a lot whiter on tremuloides.